# Circle problem with given center and radius

Tags: geometry

> The center of a circle is $(4, 0)$ and the radius $4$. Inside the circle along the radius lies a point $P(x, y)$, through this point we draw a chord such that it's perpendicular towards the radius. What curve does the points $P(x, y)$ form for which the distance $|PQ|$ is equal to the distance between point $P$ and $(2, 0)$?

I tried to translate the problem from my native language to English so apologies for the bad translation. Hopefully the picture helps.

[image]

So the equation for the circle is $(x-4)^2+(y-0)^2=4^2$ and the length of $P$ and $(2, 0)$ turned out to be $\sqrt{x^2-4x+4+y^2}$.

Also the length between $P$ and $Q$ is $|PQ| = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2 -y_1)^2}$, but I don't really see how any of these help here at all. What should i do here?

Comment: The distance $|PQ|$!

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You’ve got the first equation correct. Now notice that if you connect the center of the circle and $Q$, you get a right triangle. Now compute the distance $OP$ ($O$ is the center), and use Pythagoras to calculate $PQ$. Then equate $PQ$ to the formula you obtained earlier and you’ll get the locus of $P$.

Comment: $|OP|$ results in $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, but I don't see how i can use this for Pythagoras since I still don't know the length of the legs from the resulting right triangle?

Comment: $|OP|$ would be $\sqrt{ (x-4)^2 + y^2}$ , as the center is $(4,0)$. And clearly $OQ$ is the radius which equals $4$. Can you do it now?

Comment: Ah sorry wasn't careful enough, mistook the $O$ for origin... It seems that $|PQ| = (x-4)^2 + y^2 + 16$. Did you mean the equation of the circle by " the formula you obtained earlier"?

Comment: No, I meant the distance between $P$ and $(2,0)$. That is what you want to be equal to $PQ$! Also, consider rechecking the pythagorean formula you applied, |PQ| should be something else.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for the hint. I need to get used to seeing those right triangles in these kinds of problems.